# https letsencrypt installation on windows with WAMP

Tags: windows, git, https, wamp

Is possible to use letsencrypt with WAMP on a Windows 7? What are the steps of the complete installation process?

I installed git for windows, then run a command in the cmd.exe to clone the [client](https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt)

Now I try to run the command

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d your.domain.here
```

but is not recognised

I tried to enter the command in the power shell, and it prompted to choose application
(I don't know what application I should choose)

Comment: Do you have Python.  If I am not mistaken the Let's Encrypt client is written in Python.

Comment: I just installed pyton. Now I have to choose it after the powershell prompt?

Comment: Installing python almost certainly won't help. The client also needs a half dozen other python libraries, that the script will attempt to install via the apt-get or rpm which are Linux tools.

Comment: Is there a way to install them?

Comment: You use going to have to basically design your own client side your using a configuration that the official client doesn't support or of your not willing to use a compatible client.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Lets Encrypt is service with an API (ACME).  There are many clients that implement the ACME protocol.  The official client is just one of them.

I have seen lists of various clients in a couple places.

- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/list-of-client-implementations/2103
- https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/3vb40d/lets_encrypt_in_open_public_beta/cxlzmny

Since you are running Windows, I suspect one of the Powershell clients will be your best bet, but some of the *nix clients would almost certainly also run under cygwin if you wanted to use that.

- https://github.com/oocx/acme.net
- http://www.kingbain.com/letsencrypt-powershell-modules-for-iis-and-apache/

Of course, you could also run the official client on any Linux box or VM, and then use the 'manual' mode authentication, which doesn't require running the client on the Web server at all.

P.S.  I haven't used or reviewed any of the clients aside from acme-tiny (Linux only).  I don't know if they work well, or can be trusted to handle all the encryption securely.

Comment: So what is required me to install? I already installed python, what I have to do now?

Comment: Read through the lists of clients, pick one that looks easy to you and try it.  As I mentioned, I haven't used any of them, so I can't help much with that.

Comment: Where do I have to install the ACMESharp?

Answer (score -1):

Let's Encrypt is written in python for starters, but I do not see any bootstrapping instructions or dependency bootstrapping instructions for Windows. Here's their documentation regarding bootstrapping:

> https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contributing.html#prerequisites